# Randomize Quiz Answers Order Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, algorithm

Hi everybody I want to randomize quiz answers in Django
this is models.py

```
class Questions(models.Model):
question = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True)
point = models.PositiveIntegerField()

def questionanswers(self):
    return self.question_answers.all()

def __str__(self):
    return self.question

class Answers(models.Model):
    question_id = models.ForeignKey(Questions, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='question_answers')
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    is_true = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer
```

and this is views.py

```
question_list = Questions.objects.all().order_by('?')[:6]
        context['questions'] = question_list
      
        return context
```

and this is a template

```
  {% for answer in question.questionanswers.all %}
        <li class="col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 10px"> <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="{{answer.id}}" value="{{answer.id}}">{{answer}}</button> </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `def questionanswers(self):` `return self.question_answers.all()` → `return self.question_answers.all().order_by('?')`?